# How do I explain performance variability over PCIe bus?

Tags: cuda, gpu, data-transfer, pci-e

On my CUDA program I see large variability between different runs (upto 50%) in communication time which include host to device and device to host data transfer times over PCI Express for pinned memory. How can I explain this variability? Does it happen when the PCI controller and memory controller is busy performing other PCIe transfers? Any insight/reference is greatly appreciated. The GPU is Tesla K20c, the host is AMD Opteron 6168 with 12 cores running the Linux operating system. The PCI Express version is 2.0.

Comment: What operating system are you using and its your GPU a display or compute dedicated device?

Comment: Operating system is Linux, and host system is AMD Opteron 6168. The GPU is a compute dedicated device. I also updated the post with these information.

Comment: how many processors? just one?

Comment: Single processor with 12 cores...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The system you are doing this on is a [NUMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-uniform_memory_access) system, which means that each of the two discrete CPUs (the Opteron 6168 has two 6 core CPUs in a single package) in your host has its own memory controller and there maybe a different number of HyperTransport hops between each CPUs memory and the PCI-e controller hosting your CUDA device.

This means that, depending on CPU affinity, the thread which runs your bandwidth tests may have different latency to both host memory and the GPU. This would explain the differences in timings which you are seeing

Comment: This explains the 2-3 distinct group of timing numbers that I am seeing for my 200 set of timing values for the same program. In each group, the timing values are less than 1% apart. The groups, as I understand, are arising out of differences in the number of HyperTransport hops which depends on which core is running the host code.

Comment: You would want to look into using `numactl` to set CPU and memory affinity such that application performance is both consistent and maximized.